# How do I pass a structure that contains char strings to _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, structure

I wrote a FastCGI application for Windows IIS. It written in Visual Studio 2022 C++. Currently I am using `CreateThread` to run a function in another thread that inserts request statistics into a SQLite database. I am trying to change it to use `_beginthreadex`. I wrote a small test app to figure out the syntax. The event handle `hEvent` is passing through fine but I can't figure out the two char strings. I tried a couple ways but can't get it to work. In the state you see it below, the output for the background thread is:

```
hEvent: 11533584
dbname: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠SELECT * FROM COMPANY
```

If I uncomment out the printf of SQLSyntax, I get a bunch of horizontal bar characters.

Here is the entire test app:

```
// Threading.cpp

#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma warning (disable: 26495)

struct BackgroundStruct
{
    LPHANDLE hEvent;
    char dbname[MAX_PATH];
    char SQLSyntax[8192];
};

unsigned WINAPI ExecuteSQLThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    HANDLE hEvent = 0;
    char dbname[MAX_PATH];
    char SQLSyntax[8192];
    unsigned uReturn = 0;

    memset(dbname, 0x00, sizeof(dbname));
    memset(SQLSyntax, 0x00, sizeof(SQLSyntax));

    // gather arguments
    BackgroundStruct* strArgs = (BackgroundStruct*)lpParam;
    hEvent = *strArgs->hEvent;
    strcpy_s(dbname, sizeof(dbname), strArgs->dbname);
    strcpy_s(SQLSyntax, sizeof(SQLSyntax), strArgs->SQLSyntax);

    printf("hEvent: %d\n", (int)hEvent);
    printf("dbname: %s\n", dbname);
    //printf("SQLSyntax: %s\n", SQLSyntax);
    printf("\n");

    Sleep(3000);

    _endthreadex(uReturn);

    return uReturn;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hThread = 0;
    HANDLE hEvent = 0;
    char dbname[MAX_PATH];
    char SQLSyntax[8192];

    memset(dbname, 0x00, sizeof(dbname));
    memset(SQLSyntax, 0x00, sizeof(SQLSyntax));

    strcpy_s(dbname, sizeof(dbname), "TopwizWeb.db");
    strcpy_s(SQLSyntax, sizeof(SQLSyntax), "SELECT * FROM COMPANY");

    // allocate background structure
    BackgroundStruct* strArgs = new BackgroundStruct();

    // create event to wait for background thread to be initialized
    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    strArgs->hEvent = &hEvent;

    // copy database filename to the structure
    memset(strArgs->dbname, 0x00, sizeof(strArgs->dbname));
    strcpy_s(strArgs->dbname, sizeof(strArgs->dbname), dbname);

    // copy SQL statement to the structure
    memset(strArgs->SQLSyntax, 0x00, sizeof(strArgs->SQLSyntax));
    strcpy_s(strArgs->SQLSyntax, sizeof(strArgs->SQLSyntax), SQLSyntax);

    system("cls");
    printf("\n");
    printf("strArgs->hEvent: %d\n", (int)strArgs->hEvent);
    printf("strArgs->dbname: %s\n", strArgs->dbname);
    printf("strArgs->SQLSyntax: %s\n", strArgs->SQLSyntax);
    printf("\n");

    // create the background thread
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ExecuteSQLThread, &strArgs, 0, NULL);
    if (hThread == NULL) {
        _tprintf(L"Begin thread failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    _tprintf(L"Background thread complete!\n");

    if (hEvent != NULL) {
        CloseHandle(hEvent);
    }
    if (hThread != NULL) {
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    // cleanup
    delete strArgs;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you pass the address of the address of `strargs` when you call `begine_thread`, but treat it as the address of `strargs` when you read it back.

Comment: ... and that's why type-safe `std::thread` logically eliminates these kinds of bugs that use `LPVOID` as fertile breeding grounds.